# How does "this" function in this code Backbone sample?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, this

How does the `this` property function in this Backbone.js code sample?

Since the `use strict` directive is not specified within the code and no object is passed to any of the functions, does the Backbone.js code default to the global app object or does it do something else?

I'm assuming that `this.render()` probably renders to the DOM element specified by the `el` property passed in via the underscore template, but what about `this.$el.html`?

```
<script type="text/template" id="search_template">      
  <label>Search</label> 
  <input type="text" id="search_input" /> 
  <input type="button" id="search_button" value="Search" />
</script>
<div id="search_container"> </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var SearchView = Backbone.View.extend({ 
      initialize: function({
          this.render(); 
      }, 
      render: function(){ 
          // Compile the template using underscore 
          var template = _.template( $("#search_template").html(), {} ); 
          // Load the compiled HTML into the Backbone "el" 
          this.$el.html( template ); 
      }
  }); 
  var search_view = new SearchView({ el: $("#search_container") }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Always remember to indent and comment your code... And also don't forget to brush your teeth tonight. Don't want any extra dental bills.

Comment: I attempted to but my mobile phone refused to co-operate. Why would you be payin' muh dental bills?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code sample `this` is the pointer to the instance view of the `SearchView`.

You could create many instances of that view, and each of those would have `this` directed at itself.

---

Every view instance has two properties that point to the DOM element of that view instance. [`.el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el) points to the DOM element, and [`.$el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-$el) is a jQuery object that points to that DOM element.

The benefit of [`.$el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-$el) is that you can call any [jquery methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/) on that object.

So `this.$el.html()` means you're calling [`jQuery.html` method](http://api.jquery.com/html/) on the DOM element of that view instance.

In your code, you've compiled the template of that view and passed it to `$el.html()`, which inserts the HTML of the template into the DOM element of that view.

---

As for `this.render()` in the `initialize`, it just calls that instance's `render` method at the moment when that instance gets initialized, that is where you see the `new` keyword. New instance is created, `initialize` method is called automatically, which calls `this.render()`.

Instead of calling `this.render()` in `initialize` you could, for example, call `search_view.render()` directly after the last line of your script.